# jquery how to check response type for ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can  I determine the response type of ajax call in Jquery? At times, the server sends json response and at times it sends only the html for display purposes. Right now I am using

```
if(response.indexOf('Error'))
  //popup error message
else
 response.username
 response.address
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the header MIME type of the response?

Comment: You can check it via `typeof response=="object"`

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can try it like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "your url goes here", 
  data: "data to be sent", 
  success: function(response, status, xhr){ 
    var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
    if (ct.indexOf('html') > -1) {
      //do something
    }
    if (ct.indexOf('json') > -1) {
      // handle json here
    } 
  }
});
```

Basically it is also using indexOf but it seems more reliable.

Comment: BTW I would suggest you to use only one format if possible. Like even if you are showing some simple message, you can use the json also.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I am looking or.I wish jquery has a a shortcut for this :)

Comment: btw, for anyone interested, if you call `xhr.getResponseHeader()` (without an argument) it results to an `Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined` error

Answer (score 17):

You can simply use javascript's easy method to check the type

i.e.

```
if(typeof response=="object")
{
 // Response is javascript object
}
else
{
 // Response is HTML
}
```

If you use this method you don't have to write 2 extra parameter in the success callback.

Comment: This is a bit of a hack, but it is the most simple solution.

Comment: I always get a `"string"` there

Comment: This doesn't work. If the server returns text/html as content type it will still be an object.

Comment: That's right. In such case also it is useful as you will require to check before you convert it to Object as it is not already. The best practice is to return the correct headers.

Answer (score 12):

If the response is parsed as JSON, the `jqXHR` object will have a `responseJSON` property.

```
$.ajax(
    // ...
).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if (jqXHR.responseJSON) {
        // handle JSON
    } else {
        // handle html
    }
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    if (jqXHR.responseJSON) {
        // handle JSON
    else {
        // handle html
    }
})
```

From the [jQuery.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR):

> If json is specified, the response is parsed using jQuery.parseJSON before being passed, as an object, to the success handler. The parsed JSON object is made available through the responseJSON property of the jqXHR object.

Comment: This is not accurate because the response "hydration" relies on the format you asked. I tested a call like `$.ajax({.., dataType: 'html'})` and from the server side I send an `application/json` response, but jQuery doesn't fill the jqXHR.responseJSON field.

Comment: Indeed, but the OP wanted to know the response type. Why would you specify `dataType: 'html'` if you know the server won't send 'html'? Probably specifying `dataType` forces jQuery to use that data type, skipping the auto detect.

Comment: Yep, probably, but in my case, if I don't specify the `html` request, symfony returns the form in JSON which I don't want. Specific situations indeed.

Comment: Well, I think this solution will work but it is not generic enough, because it also works with XML (jqXHR.responseXML) but not HTML (and other types). The most generic way for me is still jqXHR.getResponseHeader('content-type').

Answer (score 8):

The answers above didnt work for me so I came up with this solution:

```
success: function(data, textStatus , xhr) {
if(xhr.responseXML.contentType == "text/html") {
    //do something with html
    }
else if(xhr.responseXML.contentType == "application/json") {
    //do something with json
    }}
```

Comment: This will likely not work if the content type is for example "text/html; charset=UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

To accept a JSON reply, you can set the reply type as JSON. I usually design my server side code so they always return JSON reply. In the event it fails to do so for whatever reason, I would get an error in my AJAX call for having incorrect JSON format and I can process the reply from server as not being non JSON.

```
error: function(response, status, xhr){ 
// do something with the reply.
}
```

Comment: off-course I could ask my server to return an logic error formatted as JSON, but when your server is down or broken, you will not get a json body.