# jQuery post, access responseType or response in callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am trying to implement a jQuery ajax post that reads like this :

```
$(this).click( function() { 
    jQuery.post('index', function() {
           console.log(responseText); 
    }, "text") 
});
```

In the above. The ajax call is definitely taking place, so I am non-plussed about that. What I am trying to wrap my head around is how I can access the responseText  in my callback function,  which is basically the Ajax response that is being received upon successful execution of the ajax call.

Pretty simple I suppose, but I can't get it :p

Answer (score 3):

It's passed as an argument to the callback. Reading [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) can be helpful :)

```
$(this).click(function() {
    jQuery.post('index', function(responseText) {
        console.log(responseText);
    }, "text")
});
```

Comment: i think it is only response, not responseText

Comment: @ParijatKalia: It's whatever you want to call it.

Comment: Er, downvote reasons, anyone? This is a little odd. -2 for both correct answers...

Comment: i downvoted by accident, and quickly removed it? let me check

Comment: oops...my apologies. I did downvote and did not remove it, did not intend to at all, thanks for letting me know about that

Comment: nope not at all.. I don't downvote at all, as can be seen from my record...there must be something messed up here, let me cross check

Comment: nope no downvoting on my end...if there is something you see, please let me know

Answer (score 2):

The response is passed as an argument to your success callback function. All you need to do is add the parameter to your function and then access it:

```
jQuery.post('index', function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

If you need more data, you'll have to go with something that is a little bit more verbose. You'd be best following the answer to this question:

[jquery how to check response type for ajax callback - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741574/jquery-how-to-check-response-type-for-ajax-call)

Comment: Well, that was the oddest voting sequence ever.

Comment: @minitech - You better believe it. I'm still stuck with a downvote and no idea why.

Comment: Same here.  I thought i am helping here. still got 2 downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Callback function returns responseText which you need to add:

```
$(this).click( function() { 
   jQuery.post('index', function(responseText) {
       console.log(responseText); 
   }, "text") 
});
```

jquery post documentation : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/