# Controller can give either json or html

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question is that the controller can give json or html piece. How to know what is it?

```
$(document).on("submit", "form.client-form", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: this.method,
        url: this.action,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result is json) { 
                ... 
            } else if (result is html) {
                $("#result").html(result);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: jquery should handle things ok if the right content type is set.

Comment: Why aren't you able to set the dataType option? What determines if the controller returns JSON or HTML? It can't be a pot luck random decision surely?

Comment: You've written your `.on()` statement incorrectly.  The event should come before the selector:  `$(document).on("submit", "form.client-form", function () {`

Comment: if (result.substring(0,1) === "{"... ;-)

Comment: does the response have proper content type set?

Comment: @RemarkLima, controller returns JSON if all is ok. In this case my script should close a context window. In case if validation fails, controller returns changed html and script have to replece it in form. How to set dataType?

Comment: @DonTomato See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ there's an option `dataType` to specify what data you're expecting. As it's only HTML on error, can you not send back JSON just with an error code as one value and the HTML as the other? Can you edit the controller? As I personally thing it could have been designed to return a single type with status code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution...found here: [jquery how to check response type for ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3741574/jquery-how-to-check-response-type-for-ajax-call)

```
$(document).on("form.client-form", "submit", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: this.method,
        url: this.action,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(result, status, xhr){ 
            var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
            if (ct.indexOf('html') > -1) {
                //html here
                $("#result").html(result);
            }
            if (ct.indexOf('json') > -1) {
                //json here
            } 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("form.client-form", "submit", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: this.method,
        url: this.action,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            try {
                var response = $.parseJSON(result); 
            }
            catch (ex){
                //something else
                $("#result").html(result);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: That answer worked 2+ years ago.  In 1.9 and later, though, `$.parseJSON()` throws an error if the JSON is not JSON.

Comment: Yeah, so looks like you do need a try/catch then. Updated my answer. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

How about using converters? Take a look at Using Converters on jquery ajax api: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/